# Visual studio design view not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Visual studio 2013 visual designer not displaying anything. 
It was working 2 hours ago but now when i open my project in visual studio it doesnt work, it only shows the outlines of panels and control but not the actual content. I am geting the same output in blend 2013.
[image: only outlines]

EDIT: Visual designer is working for Windows phone 8 projects. Its only not working for Windows 8 store apps.

Comment: Could be a low memory issue. I assume you have tried rebooting? Restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i have tried rebooting the system and also rebooted the Visual studio and blend many times....nothing worked

Comment: Try closing all open files within Visual Studio and then do a clean and rebuild of your solution...

Comment: I think you can raise this on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding done. still not working.